Is Darboux's theorem an extension of intermediate value theorem
Darboux theorem states that the intermediate value property of every bounded derivative on $[a,b]$.  Since every continuous function on closed interval $[a,b]$ must be a derivative of some functions, it must have the intermediate value property.
I wonder if there exists a sufficient and necesary condition for functions to have the intermediate value property.
PS: I have considered the Riemann function on $[0,1]$,
$$R(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac 1q & \text{if}\; x=\frac pq ,\;p,q\in \Bbb N\\
0 & \text{if}\; x \; \text {is irrational}
\end{cases} $$
which does not have the intermediate value property (for example $0\le R(x) \le 1$, but $\forall x \in [0,1], R(x)\ne \frac {\sqrt 2}2$). Can I use the Darboux's theorem to prove that there is no primitive of $R(x)$ although it is Riemann integrable?

Why do you have “bounded” on your first sentence? Doesn't the Darboux theorem simply says that, if $f$ is differentiable, then $f'$ has the intermediate value property?

Yes, you can conclude that $R(x)$ has no primitive.

@José Carlos Santos  Yes, you're right.  I say "bounded" because I want the problem to be more specific.

Well, if every derivative has the intermediate value property, then every function without that property is not a derivative, right?!

Yes, even it is Riemann integrable.

An early survey of Darboux functions is: Andrew Michael Bruckner and Jack Gary Ceder, Darboux continuity, Jahresbericht der Deutschen Mathematiker-Vereinigung 67 (1965), pp. 93-117. Possibly Section 8 on pp. 110-111 is most relevant. Of course, you'll also want to do google searches invoking this paper, such as "Darboux continuity" + "Bruckner" + "characterization".

@Dave L. Renfro  Thank you very much.
